# How do I get information about the payment method from the order object programmatically?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm trying to do some different processing after an order is placed depending on which payment method a customer uses.

In my EventSubscriber, I have the following code:

```
 public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [
      'commerce_order.place.post_transition' => 'onPlaceTransition'
    ];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onPlaceTransition(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    $order = $event->getEntity();
```

Now I want to get the name or id of the payment method that was used from the order, but when I used `kint($order)` I couldn't find a way to access the payment method.

How do I access the payment method given an `$order` object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Commerce Payment module adds the `payment_method` base field when it is enabled, see `commerce_payment_entity_base_field_info` https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/payment/commerce_payment.module#L28

You can access the payment method (and gateway) through

```
$order->get('payment_method')->first()->entity
$order->get('payment_gateway')->first()->entity
```

Example of when we get the payment method label for the order receipt email.

```
if (!$order->get('payment_method')->isEmpty()) {
  $variables['payment_method'] = [
    '#markup' => $order->get('payment_method')->first()->entity->label(),
  ];
}
```

From https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/77b25bf4889a940eed6652475c3952c36144efc0/modules/payment/commerce_payment.module#L122

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it changed at some point after 2018. I could only get the label in this way (for my offsite payment method):

```php
use Drupal\commerce_payment\Entity\PaymentGateway;

/** @var PaymentGateway $paymentGateway */
$paymentGateway = $order->get('payment_gateway')->entity;

$label = $paymentGateway->getPluginConfiguration()['display_label'];
```

`$order->get('payment_method')` was empty for my orders, but according to the code, payment methods are only set, if they are stored payment methods of the customer.