# Change workflow state with particular payment method

Tags: commerce

Right now i have a payment method called "Transferência Bancária" and I need it to change to the workflow state "Awaiting Transferencia" automatically when that payment method is selected.

Is it possible to do programmatically?

I'm stuck at:
 `$order = $event->getEntity(); if(($order->getPaymentGateway()) == ('transferencia')) { $order->set('state', 'aguardando_transferencia'); }`

on my /modules/workflowtkn/src/EventSubscriber/WorkflowTknProcessSubscriber.php

```
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::getPaymentGateway()
```

EDIT: I'm having troubles calling the function "getPaymentGateway()" because is in another module, can somebody help, please :) It has to be corresponded to the order.

I've tried `$gateway = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.commerce_payment_method_type');` but it says can't convert to string...
This:

$payment = $order->get('payment_gateway')->first()->entity

Gives me:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::escape() .

I've looked at [How do I get information about the payment method from the order object programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250863/how-do-i-get-information-about-the-payment-method-from-the-order-object-programm)
but can't figure it out.

I guess i'm failing to convert to string?

EDIT: When I use json_encode: `json_encode($order->get('payment_gateway')->first()->entity)` it only returns "{}"

Comment: At a minimum, you need to read the docs yourself before asking here.  Asking for a link to the docs is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I asked for the docs because i didn't find one for my specific issue, if there is one.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) As mentioned asking for links is off topic here, this is a Q+A site so we need the question and answer to be here, not somewhere else, or the site stagnates when the external links go down. For the remaining question the answer is definitely "yes", but again, for this format you'll need to be more specific about the problem. Add details of what you've tried, error messages, and so on. If you haven't started yet, or haven't found the commerce documentation, you're probably a bit early on to ask a question here just yet

Comment: Thank you Clive. I've been researching this for the last couple of days, but since there is no support for my issue im realy strugling. As for more information, I created a module for a custom workflow and different states. I have a manual payment method that gives the IBAN of my business for the client to transfer the money, has soon as he/her chooses it, my colegues want the order to pass to a chosen state, which is "Awaiting Transfer" in my custom workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head bashing and pure luck i found out the solution.
In order.php:

```
function getPay()
{
    return $this->get('payment_gateway')->entity->get('label');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).